# React Native NativeBase ListView with separators

Tags: react-native, native-base

I currently use React Native's ListView to display a list with section headers (`renderSectionHeader`):

```
<ListView
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
  renderRow={(rowData) => <JobListDetail firstOccurrence={rowData} />}
  renderSectionHeader={(sectionData, sectionId) => <ListSectionHeader sectionId={sectionId} />}
/>
```

The `dataSource` contains an Array of objects with the section header in the key and and an array of list items as the value like so

```
{
  Section 1: [{firstName: 'A', lastName: 'B'}, {firstName: 'C', lastName: 'D'}],
  Section 2: [{firstName: 'E', lastName: 'F'}, {firstName: 'G', lastName: 'H'}]
}
```

I was wondering whether I could achieve the same (and with a nicer looking layout) using NativeBase's `List` component. However, I couldn't find any info on how to pass in section headers:

```
<List dataArray={items} renderRow={(data) =>
    <ListItem>
        <Text>{data}</Text>
    </ListItem>
} />
```

Is that possible and if yes, are there are downsides to using it instead of React Native's `ListView`?

Comment: Did you solve this, @migu?

Comment: Did this question has answered ?

Answer (score 0):

In theory NativeBase's `List` should accept the props that React Native's `ListView` supports.

The section header could be rendered with the `itemHeader` prop:

```
<ListItem itemHeader>
  <Text>ACTION</Text>
</ListItem>
```

Comment: Tried and failed, it says `Sticky header index 0 was outside the range (0,0)`. I'm not sure if it can handle sections in the `dataArray`.